# Orders with only these products (GROUP BY and HAVING)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, relational-division

I would like to select orders with only the products with the IDs 1, 2, 3, is it possible:

Here is my actual SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders"
INNER JOIN "line_items" ON "line_items"."order_id" = "orders"."id"
INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "line_items"."product_id"
WHERE "products"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING (only line items with these products ids ?)
```

Any idea?

For example:

```
Order with products 1, 2       => OK
Order with products 1, 3       => OK
Order with products 1, 2, 3    => OK
Order with products 1, 4       => NOT OK
Order with products 1, 2, 3, 4 => NOT OK
```

Comment: By `only the products with the IDs 1, 2, 3` you mean order must have [1,2,3] all together or either one of them?

Comment: I edited the question to be more explicit

Comment: `I would like to select orders` - but then you show a query with just a count and no orders at all. Different result, different query. Please clarify. Also: is `(order_id, product_id)` defined `UNIQUE` in your table `line_items`? The table definition would tell us more.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) from PostgreSQL and the [`<@`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) contains function:

```
SELECT orders.id FROM "orders"
INNER JOIN "line_items" ON "line_items"."order_id" = "orders"."id"
GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING array_agg(line_items.product_id) <@ ARRAY[1, 2, 3];
```

Answer (score 1):

While [your presented solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22921683/939860) works (assuming the `UNIQUE` constraint you kept a secret), it will be ***painfully slow*** with bigger tables. It cannot use indexes, so the whole table `line_items` has to be aggregated before Postgres can apply the filter.

Use instead:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT i.order_id
   FROM   line_items i
   WHERE  i.product_id IN (1,2,3)
   AND    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM line_items
      WHERE  order_id = i.order_id
      AND    product_id NOT IN (1,2,3)
      )
   ) i
JOIN   orders o ON o.id = i.order_id;
```

This can use indexes and will typically be faster by orders of magnitude (difference is growing with the size of the table). Normally, `product_id`, `order_id` would be integer columns and these two multicolumn indexes would be `perfect`:

```
CREATE INDEX foo1_idx ON line_items (product_id, order_id);
CREATE INDEX foo2_idx ON line_items (order_id, product_id);
```

One of them might be the primary key already, then you only need to add the other. Assuming `orders.id` is indexed as well. All of this should be in your question.

Why these indexes? Detailed explanation in this related answer on dba.SE:
[Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

This is a case of **[relational division](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/relational-division/info)**. We assembled an arsenal of techniques under this question:
[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

The special difficulty here is to allow various combinations. The result is easier to define by what is *not* allowed.

Aside: do not needlessly double-quote legal, lower-case [identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Makes the code noisy and hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Add a WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders"
INNER JOIN "line_items" ON "line_items"."order_id" = "orders"."id"
INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "line_items"."product_id"
WHERE "products"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
      AND "line_items"."product_id" IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY orders.id
```

Comment: Remove the second WHERE and replace it with AND :-)

Comment: I think `"products"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)` and `"line_items"."product_id" IN (1,2,3)` are equivalent so that doesn't change anything.